# Fill QLineEdit with coordinates by click on QGIS canvas

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, coordinates

With a plugin I can click a button and activate a QgsMapTool, defined as:

```
class PointTool(QgsMapTool):

def __init__(self, canvas):
    QgsMapTool.__init__(self, canvas)
    self.canvas = canvas    

def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
    #Get the click
    x = event.pos().x()
    y = event.pos().y()

    point = self.canvas.getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(x, y)
    coordinates = str(point).replace('(','').replace(')','')
    coord_x = float(coordinates.split(',')[0])
    coord_y = float(coordinates.split(',')[1])

    QgsMessageLog.logMessage(str('{0:.1f}'.format(coord_x)) + ' ' + str('{0:.1f}'.format(coord_y)),'coords')
```

It shows me the coordinates in a tab 'coords' of the Log Messages Panel.

The main function I use is within the class `class mask_n_functions(QDialog, Ui_InputMask):`. And there I call the QgsMapTool as follows:

```
self.xy.clicked.connect(self.setToolActive)

def setToolActive(self):
    tool = PointTool(iface.mapCanvas())
    iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(tool)
```

Now I want to fill two QLineEdit in `class mask_n_functions(QDialog, Ui_InputMask):` with `coord_x` and `coord_y` of `class PointTool(QgsMapTool)`).

Where do I have to call `self.lblx.setText(coord_x)`?

Besides, the coordinates from canvas are rounded:

x: 620832.96 -> 620833.0

y: 5713645.90 -> 5713650.0 !!! Why?